# Reversing a negative integer results in an unexpected result

Tags: python

I wrote a code that reverses a given integer in Python. The expected inputs and outputs are as follows:

(1)

Input: `123`
Output: `321`

(2)

Input: `-123`
Output: `-321`

```
def reverse(num):
    result = 0
    repeat = len(str(num))
    original_num = num

    if original_num < 0:
        num *= -1
    else:
        pass

    for i in range(repeat):
        mod = num % 10
        num //= 10
        result = result * 10 + mod

    if original_num < 0:
        result *= -1
    return result
```

When the input is positive, the output is as I expected. But when the input is negative, the result adds an unexpected 0 to the end of the output, so when the input is `-123`, the output is `-3210`.

Can somebody tell me where this error is coming from?

Comment: You set `repeat = len(str(num))` before changing the sign of negative numbers, so `repeat` will be one too much in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `repeat = len(str(num))` before changing the sign of negative numbers and you should decrement it if num is negative. In your last iteration of `for` loop (if num is negative), `mod` will be always zero and hence, you will always get a zero appended if num is negative.

If I would be solving this problem, then I might have written it in this way:

```
def reverse(num):
    sign = num >= 0 # True if num is +ve. False if num is -ve
    num = abs(num)
    repeat = len(str(num))

    result = 0
    for i in range(repeat):
        mod = num % 10
        num //= 10
        result = result * 10 + mod

    return result if sign else -result

print(reverse(123))
print(reverse(-123))
```

There is another way to solve this problem which is bit more compact:

```
def revdigits(num):
    reverseStr = lambda s: "".join(reversed(s))
    digits = reverseStr(str(num)) if num >= 0 else ("-" + reverseStr(str(num)[1:]))
    return int(digits)

num = 123
print(revdigits(num))
print(revdigits(-num))
```

Output:

```
321
-321
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you overshoot in:

```
for i in range(repeat):
```

This is much easier:

```
def rev( num ) :
    digits = ''.join( [i for i in str(num) if i in '0123456789'] )
    maybe_sign = str(num).replace( digits, '')
    return int(maybe_sign + ''.join( reversed(digits) ))
```

The result:

```
>>> rev(123)
321
>>> rev(-123)
-321
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be happening as the length for iterations is taken before converting to a positive value. That's why the '-' sign is taken while calculating the result which gives an extra 0.
The corrected code would be

```
def reverse(num):
    result = 0
    original_num = num
    if original_num < 0:
        num *= -1
    else:
        pass
    repeat = len(str(num))
    for i in range(repeat):
        mod = num % 10
        num //= 10
        result = result * 10 + mod

    if original_num < 0:
        result *= -1
    return result

print(reverse(-123))
```

A simpler solution:

```
def reverse(num):
    factor = -1 if num < 0 else 1
    num = abs(num)
    res = 0
    for i in range(len(str(num))-1, -1, -1):
        res += (10**i)*(num%10)
        num //= 10
        print(res, num, i)
    return res*factor

print(reverse(-100))
```

If you're fine with using strings to reverse the value:

```
def reverse(num):
    return int(('-' if num<0 else '') + str(abs(num))[::-1])
print(reverse(-100))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating it, this should do the trick for you:

```py
def reverse(num):
    res=int(str(abs(num))[::-1])
#simplifies your for loop to get back the zeros at the end:
    res*=10**(len(str(abs(num)))-len(str(res)))
    if(num<0): res=-res
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

This thing works:

x = -123

```
if x<0:
    x*=-1
    x = int(str(x)[::-1])
    x *=-1
else:
    x = int(str(x)[::-1])

print(x)
```

output

```
-321
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you just have to set the *repeat* variable after testing that the *original_num* is negative. See the code below.

```
def reverse(num):
    result = 0
    original_num = num
    if original_num < 0:
        num *= -1
    repeat = len(str(num))
    for i in range(repeat):
        mod = num % 10
        num //= 10
        result = result * 10 + mod
    if original_num < 0:
        result *= -1
    return result

print(reverse(123))   # 321
print(reverse(-123))  # -321
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this one is the simplest way to get negative and positive integers reversed:

```
def reversenumber(n):
    factor = -1 if n < 0 else 1
    n = abs(n)
    rev = 0
    while n > 0:
        a = n % 10
        rev = rev * 10 + a
        n = n // 10
    return rev * factor

reversenumber(-123456)
```

**Output = -654321**

Comment: I think this one is simplest way to get reversed both negative and positive integers reversed.